# Reportlab Platypus generates empty file on second pass

Tags: python, reportlab

Minimal example:

```
import io

import lorem
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
story = [Paragraph(lorem.text(), styles["Normal"])]

with io.BytesIO() as out:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(out)
    doc.build(story) # here, you can replace story with story[:] to fix it

with open("test.pdf", "wb+") as out:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(out)
    doc.build(story[:])
```

The above code generates an empty PDF file (960 bytes, no content, white empty page). If you replace `build(story)` with `build(story[:])` in the first (`BytesIO`) block, then the `test.pdf` file is generated correctly in the second (`open` file) block.

Why?

(Python 3.9.0 amd64 on Windows, reportlab 3.5.65)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the story is consumed by doc.build. When you build a document, then the internal objects are changed inside your story, and they cannot be reused for bulding another document. I think it is not documented anywhere. Using a shallow copy is not enough, it will most likely end up in a reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError error "Flowable too large".

The safest solution is to always use a deep copy, when you want to render a story multiple times:

```
import copy
doc.build(copy.deepcopy(story))
```